# Some methods/functions simply do not work in onEdit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, authorization, urlfetch

I'm looking to call `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` based on user input on a sheet but nothing happens. No errors, just silently ignores the call. Same goes for `MailApp.sendEmail()` and `GmailApp.sendEmail()`

This is on a Google Apps domain, and only domain users are using the Google Sheet.

Comment: Are you trying to get the script executed from an "onEdit" function ?

Comment: Yes. (apparently I need 10 more characters to post so here they are)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Simple triggers like `onOpen` or `onEdit` are not able to do anything that requires authorization like sending mails because they run silently and anonymously.
This is explained in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) and discussed in this Google Apps Script community [thread](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/CMwonPyUBT8?pli=1).

You should simply rename your `onEdit` function to something else - `SpecialOnEdit` for example ? - and create an installable trigger ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)) from the script editor menu (ressources/triggers/create a new trigger...)

Comment: I tried to use this approach but faild in the SpecialOnEdit function I used GmailApp.getThreadById but it showed error (  authorization required )

Answer (score 1):

You can see an execution flow in **view** -> **execution transcript** in the script editor. Just change a cell value in spreadsheet then come back the script editor and check "execution transcript". It will show you an error if it happens.