# Google Apps Script onEdit() not accessing external API?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch, triggers

I am attempting to use `UrlFetchApp` to access an external (Enjin) API and grab a JSON blob of info. Running the function by itself (basically a get function) provides the correct HTTP response. However, when calling the function from an `onEdit()` trigger event, the Logger doesn't log any response?

Is there a difference when making external API requests from a trigger?

Here is the function itself:

```
function getUserID(name) {
  var url = "URLHERE";

  // Make a POST request with a JSON payload.
  var data = {
   'jsonrpc':'2.0',
   'id': '12345',
   'params':{
   'api_key': '123'
   },
   'method': 'UserAdmin.get'
 };
 var options = {
   'method' : 'post',
   'contentType': 'application/json',
   'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
 };

 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
 Logger.log(response.getContentText());

return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Already explained and suggested workAround can be found here:

[UrlFetchApp.fetch() simply does not work in onEdit trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112514/urlfetchapp-fetch-simply-does-not-work-in-onedit-trigger)

In short, simple trigger onEdit cannot be used to call UrlFetch. Instead, use installable triggers.

Hope that helps