# Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am trying to update Google sheet values.

"Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential."

I want to do this using API key not outh 2.0

Can anyone have any suggestions.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the same error in iOS. Is there any solution?

Comment: It's like the docs are wrong then, interesting: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#rest

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not possible. You need to use the OAuth login as indicated here in [spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate):

You can see on the authorization part that it uses OAuth scopes, therefore it follows that it uses OAuth not API KEY:

**Authorization**

Requires one of the following OAuth scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me check with service account auth.

Comment: I already have `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` but it does not work when run call Sheets API from `onEdit()`, on edit a cell. What am I missing?
When I run it manually, it works fine.
Also, I have `Execute` button disabled

Answer (score 6):

I am facing similar type of issue.

**Issue Analysis:**
Actual issue is missing of scope.

**Solution:**
Scope can be added by the following ways:

1. using enabling api
2. Adding oauth scope list. List is available here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
3. Adding scope from Code level

**Details are available here:**

1. If any scope is missing, first we need to check that related api is enabled or not. If not enabled yet, go first on google console and enable api.

Procedure is available here: https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en

2. After enabling api, sometimes you will not get your expected scope. If there is any sophisticated scope is required, you need to add those in your scope list. For this, you need to follow the procedure:

   i) *Go to google console*

   ii) *Select your project*

   iii) *In left sidebar, you will get "Oauth consent screen". Click on that button*

   iv) *You will get "Add scope" button. There is actually 3 is enlisted primarily: email, profile and openID*

   v) *You can add your expected scope here.*
3. In code level, we can also add SCOPES. In code level, **I am using singleton list.** Which is always using single scope. So when I need another scopes like user profile or user email. I can't reach those. So I changed it and got my expected result.

**Previous Code:**

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
```

**After change:**

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE,
                    Oauth2Scopes.USERINFO_EMAIL,
                    Oauth2Scopes.USERINFO_PROFILE,
                    Oauth2Scopes.PLUS_ME));
```

Comment: Is there a tutorial somewhere for beginners on how to handle authentication oauth? I know nothing about it and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this could also occur from within a google app script if the api call is being made in a simple trigger, as per the [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions):

> They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a
> simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires
> authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the
> Language service, which is anonymous.

See also: [Some methods/functions simply do not work in onEdit trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112514/some-methods-functions-simply-do-not-work-in-onedit-trigger)

Comment: Gah, just before I could post my comment elsewhere... here it is instead: @smac89 I'm sure someone will do it (I have work to do now). Rough idea: Let's say you're in round 100, so you're about to add the first 100 a-elements. You don't actually need to do that. You just need to know the high-point and the end-point of doing that.