# Can't get user info from google API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am using **Google API** to allow my users to send emails from my website. Emails are sent very well but as strange as it can appear I have trouble getting the users' information and especially his email.

**Here is the code I wrote:**

```php
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_LABELS);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_MODIFY);
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__.'/credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
$accessTokenLive = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshToken);
$client->setAccessToken($accessTokenLive);
$oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
$userData = $oauth->userinfo->get();
var_dump($userData);
```

The `$refreshToken` is fetched from the database

**I am getting an error message:**

> Request is missing the required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or another valid authentication credential.

I understand $oauth->userinfo->get() may need OAuth credentials but I can't find where to get them and most answers concerning the same issues comes out with the script above. Plus Google's API documentation says the scope is right.

I really struggle to understand how it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545966/request-is-missing-required-authentication-credential-expected-oauth-2-access-t)

Comment: I didn't find any answer corresponding to my problem on the link above

Comment: then read the googke site how to get an key https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: I have those developer keys. It's stored in the "credentials.json" file. I have access and refresh token. My script allows me to send mails, I just can't access users' infos.

Comment: I thinkl  reading this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007560/get-userinfo-from-google-oauth-2-0-php-api/23146458#23146458  that you are mising a $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile')